# C# - WinRT information: Element is already the child of another element. Additional information: No installed components were detected

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, c#-3.0

I am new to C# and I have been trying to set up a basic game (From a book), however I am at a point where it will no longer run due to the following error

> An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.dll but
>   was not handled in user code
>
> WinRT information: Element is already the child of another element.
>
> Additional information: No installed components were detected.

Looking at the code I am unable to see what is wrong;

```
    private void StartGame()
    {
        human.IsHitTestVisible = true;
        humanCaptured = false;
        progressBar.Value = 0;
        startButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        playArea.Children.Add(target);
        playArea.Children.Add(human);
        enemyTimer.Start();
        tagetTimer.Start();
    }
```

Looking at the document outline this also seems to be in the correct order;
[image: Document Outline]

The only thing to me seems to be the Xaml;

```
<Canvas x:Name="playArea" Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="10,77,10,0" >
            <StackPanel x:Name="human" Orientation="Vertical">
                <Ellipse Fill="Purple" Height="10"  Width="10" />
                <Rectangle Fill="Purple" Height="25" Width="10"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Rectangle x:Name="target" Height="53.149" Canvas.Left="1202.196" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="419.937" Width="56.008" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF4860F7" Offset="0.508"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform Rotation="46.097"/>
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
            <TextBox x:Name="gameOverText" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Game Over" Canvas.Left="428" Canvas.Top="248" Height="107" Width="413" FontSize="72" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic"/>
            <Canvas.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF1BAE78" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFDCEE3B"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Canvas.Background>
</Canvas>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It is not very clear why you call playArea.Children.Add() when these elements are already children of playArea.  As shown by both the xaml and the outline.  Probably what it is complaining about.  Put a big arrow on the statement that throws this exception.  And comment out these two calls, if my guess is right then it solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks that did work, I am not 100% to be fair this is my first real attempt at c# and I am following a book (Head First) probably where I am going wrong.

Comment: I will add my code in below so this might make more sense:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.UI.Popups; //This is used for massage box within a blank applocation. 

using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation;

// The Basic Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234237

namespace Save_The_Humans
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A basic page that provides characteristics common to most applications.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Save_The_Humans.Common.LayoutAwarePage
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        DispatcherTimer enemyTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        DispatcherTimer tagetTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        bool humanCaptured = false;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            enemyTimer.Tick += enemyTimer_Tick;
            enemyTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

            tagetTimer.Tick += tagetTimer_Tick;
            tagetTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.1);
        }

        void tagetTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            progressBar.Value += 1;
            if (progressBar.Value >= progressBar.Maximum)
                EndTheGame();

        }

        private void EndTheGame()
        {
            if (!playArea.Children.Contains(gameOverText))
            {
                enemyTimer.Stop();
                tagetTimer.Stop();
                humanCaptured = false;
                startButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                playArea.Children.Add(gameOverText);
            }
        }

        void enemyTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            AddEnemy();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Populates the page with content passed during navigation.  Any saved state is also
        /// provided when recreating a page from a prior session.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="navigationParameter">The parameter value passed to
        /// <see cref="Frame.Navigate(Type, Object)"/> when this page was initially requested.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="pageState">A dictionary of state preserved by this page during an earlier
        /// session.  This will be null the first time a page is visited.</param>
        protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Preserves state associated with this page in case the application is suspended or the
        /// page is discarded from the navigation cache.  Values must conform to the serialization
        /// requirements of <see cref="SuspensionManager.SessionState"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pageState">An empty dictionary to be populated with serializable state.</param>
        protected override void SaveState(Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
        {
        }
        private void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StartGame();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the game.
        /// </summary>
        public void StartGame()
        {
            human.IsHitTestVisible = true;
            humanCaptured = false;
            progressBar.Value = 0;
            startButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            /*playArea.Children.Add(target);
            playArea.Children.Add(human);*/
            enemyTimer.Start();
            tagetTimer.Start();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the animation, below is the enemy method.
        /// </summary>
        private void AddEnemy()
        {
            ContentControl enemy = new ContentControl();
            enemy.Template = Resources["EnemyTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
            AnimateEnemy(enemy, 0, playArea.ActualWidth - 100, "(Canvas.Left)");
            AnimateEnemy(enemy, random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 100),
                random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 100), "(Canvas.Top)");
            playArea.Children.Add(enemy);
        }

        private void AnimateEnemy(ContentControl enemy, double from, double to, string properyToAnimate)
        {
            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard() { AutoReverse = true, RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever };
            DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation()
            {
                From = from,
                To = to,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next(4, 6)))
            };
            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, enemy);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, properyToAnimate);
            storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
            storyboard.Begin();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// async needs to be a part of the method to show message box!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private async void About_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Creating instance for the MessageDialog Class  
            //and passing the message in it's Constructor
            MessageDialog msgbox = new MessageDialog("Created by");
            //Calling the Show method of MessageDialog class  
            //which will show the MessageBox  
            await msgbox.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
}
```